# Yocto Recipe - Trying to fetch source from private Azure GIT repository

Tags: git, azure-devops, yocto, yocto-recipe

`Hi

I am in the process of creating a yocto Recipe that will fetch the source from a private Azure GIT repository.
SSH URL works on UBUNTU as a standalone, I don’t see any issues while cloning via SSH URL using GIT commands or GIT GUI.

However, the do-fetch() function fails when the recipe tries to fetch using the same SSH URL used for  SRC_URI

I am not sure why fetch fails here, is there any specific syntax or procedure that needs to be followed to fetch a private GIT repository?

Any help on this will significantly help us

SSH URL which works on UBUNTU

**git@ssh.dev.azure.com:v3/CompanyName>/ProjectName/TestYoctoSourceUri**

SRI command used in my recipe

**SRC_URI = "git://git@ssh.dev.azure.com:v3/CompanyName/ProjectName/TestYoctoSourceUri;pocrotol=ssh;branch=master;destsuffix=git/common**"

**Have changed.SSH configuration to add SSH key and port number**

Host dev.azure.com

HostName dev.azure.com

Port 443

PreferredAuthentications publickey

IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa``

Comment: Can you share the error you got when you running the command in Yocto Recipe?

Comment: Hi here is the error message   ERROR: XXX_recip-0.0.1-r0 do_fetch: Failed to fetch URL git://git@ssh.dev.azure.com:v3/CompanyName/ProjectName/TestYoctoSourceUri;pocrotol=ssh;branch=master;destsuffix=git/common, attempting MIRRORS if available

Comment: There is a typo in the URL: pocrotol => protocol

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the character `:` in the URL is not supported in Yocto Recipe.

You can try to replace the `:` with `/` in the URL .

For example:

```
SRC_URI = "git://git@ssh.dev.azure.com/v3/CompanyName/ProjectName/TestYoctoSourceUri;pocrotol=ssh;branch=master;destsuffix=git/common"
```

Comment: I tried this but , do_fetch() still fails to fetch files from the repo